# Function to create new, previously undefined variable

Tags: php

Sorry for such a lame title, but I just had no idea what to put there, hope you understand it. Plus, I have no idea if similar question has been asked before, because I don't know the proper keywords for it - therefore couldn't google it too.

Basicly... When looking at [`preg_match_all();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php), they got this **matches** parameter that will create new array defined in function, and give us the ability to access it after function execution.

And the question is.. How can I implement such a feature in my own function? But that it could create single variable and/or array.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are referring to function [parameters passed by reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.by-reference), are you not?

```
function putValInVar(&$myVar, $myVal){
    $myVar = $myVal;
}

$myVar = 1;
putValInVar($myVar, 2);

echo $myVar; // outputs '2', but will output '1' if we remove the '&' //
```

By default function arguments in PHP are passed by value. This means that new variables are created at each function call and those variables will exist only inside the function, not affecting anything outside it.

To specify that an argument should be used *by reference* the syntax is to append an `&` before declaring it in the function header. This will instruct PHP to use the passed variable inside the function rather than creating a copy of it.

*Exception: Objects are always passed by reference.* (Well... Not really, but it's complicated. See the comment thread for more info.)

Comment: there is no need to define `$myVar` before calling `putValInVar()`

Comment: @kemp Of course not, but I wanted to better illustrate the value change.

Comment: No, objects are not passed by reference unless you use `&` also. By default, references to them are passed by value. That means multiple references to the same object, not the original object reference.

Comment: This indeed is what I was looking for! Accepted! But, but... Is there a way to make this *parameter passed by reference* not obligate? Like you can do with `function myFunction($obligate, $notObligate = "somevalue") {}`

Comment: @BoltClock It's what [this comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php#92348) points out, is it not? But this applies to any PHP value, not just objects!

Comment: @Tom You can make it optional. It's not a problem. If you don't supply the variable when calling one will be created, but will die with the function because there was not external reference.

Comment: @Alin: Not exactly. Non-object types are passed, copy-on-write, by value. Object types are passed by reference-value. If you made an object and a function which accepts it by reference and turns it into a non-object, the object in the calling scope will be changed to that non-object value. If you specify the parameter without the `&`, only the reference to the object **owned by the function** gets overwritten with that value.

Comment: @Alin Oh, that makes sense! Well, thanks a lot for your effort, will put this in practice later on. It's possible, that more questions will then pop up.

Comment: @BoltClock [I see](http://codepad.org/IyoguOZg) what you were trying to say, now. It makes perfect sense and thank you for bringing it out. Actually object are passed by value just like the other variables, the catch is that they only contain the pointers to the *physical objects*.

Comment: @Alin: Yup, that's the basic idea behind it.

Comment: @BoltClock I think I'll keep the phrase `Objects are always passed by reference.` because it has a certain truth value, at least on the surface. What do you think?

Comment: @Alin: Maybe not. I have seen that kind of statement bother some other people here on SO...

Answer (score 4):

`preg_match_all()` accepts a reference to an array, which in its own scope is called `$matches`. As seen in the function prototype:

```
array &$matches
```

If you call the function and pass in a variable, if it does not already exist in the calling scope it will be created. So in your user-defined function, you accept a parameter by reference using `&`, then work with it inside your function. Create your outer-scope variable by simply declaring it in your function call, like you the way you call `preg_match_all()` with `$matches`.

An example:

```
function foo(&$bar) {
    $bar = 'baz';
}

// Declare a variable and pass it to foo()
foo($variable);
echo $variable; // baz
```

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are asking for is [passing-by-reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php). What preg_match_all basically does to "create" an array  variable outside its scope is:

```
 function preg_match_all($foo, $bar, & $new_var) {
     $new_var = array(1,2,3);
 }
```

The crucial point here is `&` in the function definition. This allows you to overwrite variables in the outer scope when passed.

Stylistically this should be used with care. Try to return arrays or results instead of doing it via reference passing.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
$myvariable = runfunction();

function runfunction() {
//do some code assign result to variable (ie $result)
return $result;
}
```

Or

```
global $result;
function runfunction() {
global $result;
$result = 'something';
}
```

Comment: No, because `preg_match_all()` does not return the `$matches` array.

Comment: Can't see that this is much of an issue defining with the result. but if not set it in a global variable?